# Sorting XML in order

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xsd

I have converted an xsd to code using the XSD2Code Generator. The tool works great and I am serializing xml using the code to send a request to web service.

Here is the part of the sample from xml generated.

```
<OrderDetails>
  <StockLine>        
    <StockCode>StockCode1</StockCode>
    <StockDescription>Description1</StockDescription>
  </StockLine>
  <StockLine>        
    <StockCode>StockCode2</StockCode>
    <StockDescription>Description2</StockDescription>        
  </StockLine>
  <CommentLine>        
    <Comment>Comment1</Comment>        
  </CommentLine>
  <CommentLine>       
    <Comment>Comment2</Comment>        
  </CommentLine>
</OrderDetails>
```

I am adding each item from my data table which has three columns Stockcode, Description, and Comment. See the sample code shown below. The logic I expected was to insert  node right after  if Datarow is not null for Comment column in my data table. But instead it is adding all the  and then adding .

The when using the xsd serialization class has two lists, one for Stockline and another for comments. When serializing xml it follows the order and inserts them all  items from the list and then .

```
PORTOIDOC.OrderDetails orderDetails = new PORTOIDOC.OrderDetails();
for (int i = 0; i < PODatatTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    PORTOIDOC.StockLine stkline = new PORTOIDOC.StockLine();                
    stkline.StockCode = PODatatTable.Rows[i]["StockCode"].ToString();
    stkline.StockDescription = PODatatTable.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();
    orderDetails.StockLine.Add(stkline);
    PORTOIDOC.CommentLine cmnt = new PORTOIDOC.CommentLine();                
    if (PODatatTable.Rows[i]["Comment"] != null)
    {
        cmnt.Comment = PODatatTable.Rows[i]["Comment"].ToString();
        orderDetails.CommentLine.Add(cmnt);
    }

}
```

This is what I ideally need form my xml to look like. If Datarow in Datatable has Comment then the Comment Node should be inserted right after StockLine.

```
<OrderDetails>
  <StockLine>        
    <StockCode>StockCode1</StockCode>
    <StockDescription>Description1</StockDescription>
  </StockLine>
  <CommentLine>        
    <Comment>Comment1</Comment>        
  </CommentLine>
  <StockLine>        
    <StockCode>StockCode2</StockCode>
    <StockDescription>Description2</StockDescription>        
  </StockLine>      
  <CommentLine>       
    <Comment>Comment2</Comment>        
  </CommentLine>
</OrderDetails>
```

How can I sort my XML after it is generated in an order aligning with Datatable.?

OrderDetails Class

```
public OrderDetails()
        {
            this.freightLineField = new List<FreightLine>();
            this.miscChargeLineField = new List<MiscChargeLine>();
            this.commentLineField = new List<CommentLine>();
            this.stockLineField = new List<StockLine>();
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("StockLine", Order = 0)]
        public List<StockLine> StockLine
        {
            get
            {
                return this.stockLineField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.stockLineField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CommentLine", Order = 1)]
        public List<CommentLine> CommentLine
        {
            get
            {
                return this.commentLineField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.commentLineField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MiscChargeLine", Order = 2)]
        public List<MiscChargeLine> MiscChargeLine
        {
            get
            {
                return this.miscChargeLineField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.miscChargeLineField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FreightLine", Order = 3)]
        public List<FreightLine> FreightLine
        {
            get
            {
                return this.freightLineField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.freightLineField = value;
            }
        }

        private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
        {
            get
            {
                if ((serializer == null))
                {
                    serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderDetails));
                }
                return serializer;
            }
        }

        #region Serialize/Deserialize
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes current OrderDetails object into an XML document
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>string XML value</returns>
        public virtual string Serialize()
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
            System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
            try
            {
                memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream);
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((streamReader != null))
                {
                    streamReader.Dispose();
                }
                if ((memoryStream != null))
                {
                    memoryStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication86
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("StockCode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("StockDescription", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));

            XElement orderDetails = doc.Descendants("OrderDetails").FirstOrDefault();

            DataRow newRow = null;
            foreach(XElement orderDetail in orderDetails.Elements())
            {

                switch (orderDetail.Name.LocalName)
                {
                    case "StockLine":
                        newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                        newRow["StockCode"] = (string)orderDetail.Descendants("StockCode").FirstOrDefault();
                        newRow["StockDescription"] = (string)orderDetail.Descendants("StockDescription").FirstOrDefault();
                        break;
                    case "CommentLine":
                           newRow["Comment"] = (string)orderDetail.Descendants("Comment").FirstOrDefault();
                        break;
                }


            }


         }

    }



}
```

Comment: I need xml to match the row data. Not xml to enter data in a datatable. If Datatable has column "StockCode","StockDescription" & "Comment". The xml should be in the same order as of rows. Node Stockline then Node CommentLine if comment row in my datat table has value if not then next StockLine

Comment: Then serialize again after you sort.  Why sort the xml?

Comment: I am using an Xsd to code generated file. It is easy to serialize with it as it will all other elements that are by default required to send soap request. If use the same serialize method then it will create xml in the same order.

Comment: Then use the DataTable to create the xml.  It is very easy to so the DataTable so why make things difficult.  You can then serialize the DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can sort using LINQ, but I'm thinking that you are actually trying to imply association by order instead of by containment. Assuming Comment1 is associated with Stockcode1, and Comment2 belongs to Comment2, perhaps a structure like this will better meet your need:

```
<OrderDetails>
  <StockLine>        
    <StockCode>StockCode1</StockCode>
      <StockDescription>Description1</StockDescription>
      <CommentLine>        
        <Comment>Comment1</Comment>        
      </CommentLine>
  </StockLine>
  <StockLine>        
      <StockCode>StockCode2</StockCode>
      <StockDescription>Description2</StockDescription>
      <CommentLine>       
        <Comment>Comment2</Comment>        
      </CommentLine>        
  </StockLine>      
</OrderDetails>
```

Then you can slightly change your parsing logic to process the comments associated with each StockLine.

Comment: I can't contain comment under Stockline. When posting this XML to web service it will throw an error for incorrect format.

Comment: Okay, got it.  I think I see your problem. Your OrderDetails object contains two collections, one for stocklines and one for comments, which get serialized separately, thus the change of order from what you would like. Can you create a single collection that you can add either StockLine objects or CommentLine objects to, in the order that you would like? Then as the OrderDetails is serialized, it will maintain the original order the you are aiming for.
If you post your OrderDetails class, I think I can give some guidance.